# elementary ordinary differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)=a e^{i\lambda x}+be^{-i\lambda x}.$ Then $f$ clearly solves  (if viewed as classical or even weak solution) the equation $\Delta u-\lambda^2u=0.$ Are all the $C^{\infty}$-solutions of this form?

*Lacking the boundary conditions makes the problem ill-possed but still it is relevant to talk about uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. Let $u_1 = u$ and $u_2 = u'$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray}
u_1' &= u_2\\
u_2' &=-\lambda^2 u_1
\end{eqnarray}
or, denoting by ${\bf u}= \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u_1 \\
u_2
\end{array} \right)$ we get
\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf u}' = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-\lambda^2 & 0
\end{array} \right)\cdot {\bf u}
\end{eqnarray}
or ${\bf u}'= A\cdot {\bf u}$ where $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-\lambda^2 & 0
\end{array} \right)$. Let ${\bf v}= \exp( - tA) \cdot {\bf u}$. Then
$${\bf v}' =  \exp(-tA)(-A) {\bf u} + \exp(-tA) {\bf u}' = \exp(-tA)( - A{\bf u} + A{\bf u})= {\bf 0}$$
and so ${\bf v} =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{array} \right)$ is constant ${\bf v} \equiv \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{array} \right)$ and so ${\bf u} = \exp ( t A) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
c_1 \\
c_2
\end{array} \right)$. We calculate 
$$\exp ( t A) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\cos(\lambda t) & \frac{\sin(\lambda t)}{\lambda} \\
- \lambda \sin ( \lambda t) & \cos ( \lambda t)
\end{array} \right)$$
and so $u=u_1$ is a linear combination of $\cos(\lambda t)$ and $\sin(\lambda t)$.